# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/converted' . Trying to convert .mp3 file to .wav in python pydub

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I am trying to convert .mp3 extension file to .wav. This is my simple code.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("english.mp3")
sound.export("/converted", format="wav")
```

After executing this code it shows  `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/converted'` .
I changed permission for this directory.But still it  shows same error please help me.

Comment: Can you show the permissions (e.g. the ls -l output if you are on Linux) and add that info to your question?

Comment: Yes. I am using linux. i run this command `sudo chmod 777 -R /home/desktop/kivy/start/converted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the code [audio_segment.py](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py#L551) you need to set file path, mean full file path:

```
sound.export("/home/desktop/kivy/start/converted/english.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: I already tried this it shows `No such file or directory: '/converted/english.wav'
`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me on Windows. Instead, I found that my anti-virus was flagging the activity as suspicious and denying access. After white-listing python.exe, the issue was fixed.